# How to get the most friendly terminal output?

Tags: linux, terminal

Do you remember, in the old 80's movies, when the computer operator can read the screen at the same time it was printed in the monitor?. Each caracter was printed once the previus one had been printed, and the lines so.At now, when we list the pages using ls, we se the last page if we don't use the less pipeline. How can we get this effect?

Comment: I have find an easy to use command named "pv". At this time I'm trying to use a confortable output with the alias: alias ls='ls -lha --color | pv --quiet --rate-limit 1566 -i 0.1'

Comment: I don't think this Q is about programming, which is what StackOverflow is about. But, I'm not really sure what you're asking. At least, you should include you `pv` command as part of your Q (and then delete your comment). You should also define for readers (*in the body of your Q*), how a monitor is different than a screen. In modern terms, they are the same. Use the `{}` edit tool on highlighted text so code appears proper formatted (or user 4 spaces at the front of each line). Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.